# Submit button not reaching server with select list

Tags: html

I'm finding that when I use the following html code in Chrome and Mozilla and hit enter rather than clicking the submit button, the submit button is included with the selection and password to the server, but when I use Explorer only the selection and password is included. I'm using Explorer 9. Is there something I'm missing or is there another way to get Explorer to incluce the button information even though you hit enter.

```
<form method=post action=/plm.cgi>
    <select name="dropdown">
        <option value="Maths" selected>Maths</option>
        <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    </select>
    <input type=password name=AdminPassWord size=11> AdminPassword
    <input type="submit" name="operation"  value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give submit input a name:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: I actually tried that. I left that out of my example. It still doesn't return the button information to the server.